# Как сверстать такое расположение блоков (желательно на флексах)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

Как сверстать такое расположение блоков?

Желательно на флексах, чтобы они уходили друг под друга при сжатии окна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у родителя сделать display:flex и внутри 2 колонки. В колонке натыканы блоки нужные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать флексами и медиа вот так:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

.title {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;

  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .list {
    max-height: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
      <h1 class="title">Наши работы:</h1>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <a href="#">Еще работы ---></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.list {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #acacac;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```